# lmer analysis for 58 people 4 timepoints, advice on setting the model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I’m looking for some advice on analysing this data. I think I need a multilevel model.

I have 58 participants measured progesterone and a factor at 4 timepoints. I would like to do a model to see how progesterone predicts factor1, but it should probably take into account repeated measurements per individual (4* per person).

Thus if progesterone increases with time, so should Factor 1.
Each ID has a repeated measure at 4 timepoints, and the time between each timepoint is the same. [image: The attached image shows factor1~progesterone for 4 timepoints (1,3,5,7 instead of 1,2,3,4 but its the same thing)]

I also know that between time 1-3, progesterone will increase (perhaps it will increase even more between 2 and 3), and between time 3 and 4 progesterone will drop, for all. I was thinking of a model like

mod<-lmer(Factor1 ~ timepoint + progesterone + (1 | ID ) ,data = df) which takes into account ID, but would really love some advice.
For example should I also include (progesterone|ID) or (progesterone|timepoint)?

I think a linear relationship between progesterone and factor1 is likely, but I'm not sure.

Here is similar data to what I am using:

```
set.seed(123)

# Number of participants and timepoints
num_part <- 58
num_timepoints <- 4

# Generate progesterone data
progesterone <- rnorm(num_part * num_timepoints, mean = 0, sd = 1)
progesterone[is.na(progesterone)] <- -3.8  # Replace NA with the specified value

# Ensure that the generated progesterone values fall within the desired range
progesterone <- pmin(pmax(progesterone, -3.8), 1.4)

# Generate Factor1 data
factor1 <- rnorm(num_part * num_timepoints, mean = 0.03, sd = 1)
factor1 <- pmin(pmax(factor1, -1.840773), 2.149765)  # Ensure values are within the desired range

# Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:num_part, each = num_timepoints),
  timepoint = rep(1:num_timepoints, times = num_part),
  progesterone = progesterone,
  Factor1 = factor1
)
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an answer, but there is more to warn you about here than can fit nicely into comments.

A big potential problem is that your 2 predictors, `timepoint` and `log10(progesterone)`, are highly correlated. Almost all the observations with `log10(progesterone) > 0.6` are at time points `v3` and `v5`, which are also the 2 days with most of the data showing `Factor1 > 0`. There is very little spread in the `log10(progesterone)` values at time points `v3` and `v5`, making it hard to discern `Factor1`/`log10(progesterone)` associations within those days. And at time points `v1` and `v7` there isn't any obvious overall association between `Factor1` and `log10(progesterone)`, although that might be masked by the differences among individuals.

The fear is that, even after taking intra-subject correlations into account, you will have a very high variance inflation factor for your fixed predictors, which makes it hard to distinguish separate associations of either predictor with the `Factor1` outcome variable. The correlation might end up making both their regression coefficients "statistically insignificant" even though one or the other (or both together) are highly associated with `Factor1` values.

The correlation could also make the suggestion in the answer from Manoj Kumar, to include a `timepoint:log10(progesterone)` interaction in the model, somewhat problematic. That's often a good idea, but for these data you aren't going to have many low `log10(progesterone)` values at time points `v3` and `v5`, or many high `log10(progesterone)` values at time points `v1` and `v7`. Thus the interaction terms might not provide much beyond what you would get just from the `timepoint` predictor itself.

It looks like these individuals had some treatment or experienced some event that led to large increases in *both* `Factor1` and `log10(progesterone)` at time points `v3` and `v5`. If that's the case, then it will be hard to argue that the progesterone values "predict" `Factor1` levels in general. Those two values might just, under this set of conditions, be affected in parallel by the treatment or event.

You should at least consider the recommendations by Frank Harrell, in comments on another answer, to use (1) flexible modeling of the `log10(progesterone)` predictor with a regression spline and (2) [generalized least squares](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long) to handle the intra-individual correlations.

If I understand the design correctly, you might consider a "multivariate" model in the sense of multiple outcomes, with both `Factor1` and `log10(progesterone)` as outcomes and the `timepoint` values as predictors. That approach can illustrate the correlations between the outcomes without implying that one "predicts" the other.

Answer (score 2):

Your model `mod <- lmer(Factor1 ~ timepoint + progesterone + (1 | ID), data = df)` represents fixed effects for timepoint and progesterone, and a random intercept for each participant. Basically, here random intercept accounts for the repeated measurements within individuals.

Given additional information by you that the progesterone increases from time 1 to 3 and then drops at time 4 for all participants, did you try to incorporate this into the model?

If not, you could try something like:: `mod <- lmer(Factor1 ~ timepoint + progesterone + progesterone:timepoint + (1 | ID), data = df)`

Above suggestion, for example, would represent the fixed effects for timepoint, progesterone, and their interaction, as well as a random intercept for each participant in your data.

My suggestion, you should also check the assumptions of your model, for example, the normality of residuals and homoscedasticity etc., and then you should consider choosing a model based on the fit of that model on your data.

Comment: Handling dependence by modeling ID is not necessarily the most appropriate way to handle within-person correlations.  You can model dependence directly.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/re).  See also [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long).

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks... i just thought of a suggestion :) may be you could answer to OP's question in the other possible ways too..

Comment: I assume you are referring to possible nonlinearity of progesterone vs factor1.  That can also be handled with a regression spline.